# plot a normal distribution curve and histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Please, I want to know how I can plot a normal distribution plot.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import pylab as pl

h=[27.3,27.6,27.5,27.6,27.3,27.6,27.9,27.5,27.4,27.5,27.5,27.4,27.1,27.0,27.3,27.4]

fit = stats.norm.pdf(h, np.mean(h), np.std(h))  #this is a fitting indeed

pl.plot(h,fit,'-o')
pl.hist(h,density=True)      #use this to draw histogram of your data
pl.show()                    #use may also need add this
```

I tried this but the curve is very rough.

Comment: Do you want to use `range(len(fit))` istead of `h` for the `x` value inside the `plot()` and `hist()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply sort your list `h`.

Using sorted like this:

```
h = sorted([27.3,27.6,27.5,27.6,27.3,27.6,27.9,27.5,27.4,27.5,27.5,27.4,27.1,27.0,27.3,27.4])
```

Alternatively, you can also use `h.sort()`.

```
h =[27.3,27.6,27.5,27.6,27.3,27.6,27.9,27.5,27.4,27.5,27.5,27.4,27.1,27.0,27.3,27.4]
h.sort()
```

Output:
[image]

In order to get a smooth distribution curve, you can use `seaborn.distplot()`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import scipy

h=[27.3,27.6,27.5,27.6,27.3,27.6,27.9,27.5,27.4,27.5,27.5,27.4,27.1,27.0,27.3,27.4]
ax = sns.distplot(h,fit=scipy.stats.norm, kde=False, hist=True, color='r')
ax.plot()
```

Output:

[image]

For more information on `seaborn.distplot()`, check [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) official documentation.

Comment: Thanks but the curve is not smooth sir

Comment: @AwomaVICTORSEGUN, you haven't mentioned anywhere that you wanted a smooth curve. I just pointed out a mistake in your code. The output from your code was no way near to the output using sorted list h.